# Effects of duplicate values in the subset of the predictors in ML

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I am working on a classification problem with an expanded dataset. Assume that the initial data is the following. For the sake of demonstration, let us assume that we have only two predictor columns, A and B, (but in reality, there're 30+ of them), and one target variable Y. The problem with that dataset is a relatively small number of training points, so the aim is to expand the dataset.

| A | B | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

We can collect more data and expand the dataset by adding column C ranging, say, from 1 to 7. So, each row is duplicated 7 times and **the target is sometimes affected by C**. In this example, **C** may represent the day of the week. **So, it means that the target is changing depending on the day of the week and other columns, A and B, that have fixed values throughout the week.**

The resulting data is the following

| A | B | **C** | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | **1** | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | **2** | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | **3** | 1 |
| ... | ... | **...** | ... |
| 1 | 2 | **7** | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | **1** | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | **2** | 0 |
| ... | ... | **...** | ... |

**EDIT**
Assume that initial data corresponds to C = 7 i.e. we know about A, B only on Sundays. However, we know that Y also depends on the day of the week and we can track the target on each day of the week but we can access A and B only in the end of the week

**MY QUESTIONS**
How does fitting ML models on such type of data affect inference and forecasting?
Can we use K-fold CV to estimate the error here? I see the problem here is that during a split to train and test sets, the sets will be extremely similar and most observations will differ only in one column ( and target), so the estimation of the error is not reliable.
Can anyone suggest or reference something on the procedures of working with such type of data?

Comment: What do you mean by "expanding" the dataset? Are you collecting new data? Or where do the new rows come from?

Comment: @StephanKolassa made an edit

Comment: "most observations will differ only in one column" - why? In cross-validating, you would still have data from different weeks in each fold, no? I am imagining having daily retail sales, but only having promotion or price information as of Saturday each week. No, this is not good. I would say this falls under "garbage data", and there is little one can do about it, short of collecting better data.